# SQL In Clause Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, multiple-columns, in-clause, in-operator

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabl tabb
WHERE (tabb.col1, tabb.col2) IN ( (1,2), (3,4))
```

The above works in Oracle but I am trying to run in a proprietary SQL engine which doesn't support the above query formation with multiple columns in IN.

I am trying to find combinations of 1,2 and 3,4 in the DB.

Please help me with any alternatives for achieving the above.

I am looking for ways to pass a list of values for col1 and col2 from Java at one shot, so '=' might not be an option as it might require two SQL statements for achieving the above.

Comment: it would be easier with sample data, you want the result where col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 or col1 = 3 and col2 = 4 ?

Comment: Yes I want the result where col1 = 1 and col2 = 2 or col1 = 3 and col2 = 4.

Comment: I think @hall stephenk answer is correct...

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Tabl tabb
WHERE
    (tabb.col1 = 1 AND tabb.col2 = 2) OR
    (tabb.col1 = 3 AND tabb.col2 = 4)
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer earlier, please see the edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tabl tabb
inner join (
    select 1 a, 2 b 
    union select 3, 4
) x
on tabb.col1 = x.a
and tabb.col2 = x.b
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, the values 1,2,3,4 are static values and not a result of select.

Answer (score 0):

In case of numeric columns and supposing the values are bounded to a specific range
more values can be packed into one number using some formula

for instance supposing the values of col1 and col2 are from 1 to 1000
the formula

```
  N = 10000 * col1 + col2
```

can be used and in the example the select would be

```
  SELECT * FROM Tabl tabb WHERE (10000 * tabb.col1 + tabb.col2) IN ( 10002, 30004)
```

In general string concatenation can be used to combine several column values, for example

```
  SELECT * FROM Tabl tabb WHERE (tabb.col1||"&"||tabb.col2) IN ( "1&2", "3&4")
```